# How to work with Page control using NSTimer for automatic scrolling in swift4

Tags: ios, swift4, nstimer, uipagecontrol

I am new to iOS.I am trying to do the page control using NSTimer for automatic scrolling and also I want to change the shape of dots in page control .I need page control with rectangle boxes.If anyone helps me ,would be great.

Comment: Have you tried anything already ? Try something and update your question with any queries then.

Comment: https://github.com/satishVekariya/MarqueeScroll

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
var index = 0    
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.4, target: self, selector: #selector(self.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func update()  {
    index = index + 1
    let x = CGFloat(index) * scrollView.frame.size.width
    scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:x, y:0), animated: true)
}
```

Comment: works like a charm, nice work done @sidharth Khanna.

Answer (score 2):

I have an example for collection view auto scroll like [ganna.com](https://gaana.com/) in ios or android application.

For `Swift 4.2`

code:

```
var timer: Timer?

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView : UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.reloadData()
    startTimer()
}

func startTimer() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(scrollAutomatically), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}


@objc func scrollAutomatically(_ timer1: Timer) {
    for cell in collectionView.visibleCells {
        if banner.count == 1 {
            return
        }
        let indexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)!
        if indexPath.row < (banner.count - 1) {
            let indexPath1 = IndexPath.init(row: indexPath.row + 1, section: indexPath.section)
            collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath1, at: .right, animated: true)
            pageControl.currentPage = indexPath1.row
        }
        else {
            let indexPath1 = IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: indexPath.section)
            collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath1, at: .left, animated: true)
            pageControl.currentPage = indexPath1.row
        }
    }
}
```

`banner.Count` => a number of cells containing a collection view

I hope you find this useful.